# Work on object of type GenericType<T> regardless of T

Tags: c#, generics, casting

In case two classes are of the same GenericType<> regardless of T I would like to do some stuff. Is this possible?

```
// class is given; I can't change it!!
public class MyGeneric<T> : MyBaseClass where T : struct, IComparable, IConvertible
{
    public T MyProperty { get; set; }
}


public void DoStuff(MyBaseClass objA, MyBaseClass objB)
{
    ...
    if (objA.GetType().IsGenericType && objA.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MyGeneric<>) &&
            objA.GetType() == objB.GetType())
    {
        //here I know that my objects do have a "MyProperty"
                //I would like to do something like:
        if (((MyGeneric<T>)objA).MyProperty.CompareTo(((MyGeneric<T>)objB).MyProperty) > 0)  //doesn't work!!!!
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be made to work if you change the `DoStuff` method signature to

```
public void DoStuff<T>(MyBaseClass objA, MyBaseClass objB)
    where T : struct, IComparable, IConvertible
{
    // ...
}
```

However, you would have to know the type of `T` at compile time in order to call the method; I 'm not sure if this would solve your problem.

Apart from that, the other solution is to use reflection:

```
var valueA = (IComparable)objA.GetType().GetProperty("MyProperty").GetValue(objA, null);
var valueB = (IComparable)objB.GetType().GetProperty("MyProperty").GetValue(objB, null);
if (valueA.CompareTo(valueB) > 0) {
    // ...            
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jon. I don't know the type of T at compile time!

Answer (score 0):

This really doesn't make any sense:

1. `objA.GetType() == objB.GetType()` ensures, that they **are** of the same type, i.e. *not* independent from `T`
2. If point 1 would be solved by simply removing this check, it still would make no sense to compare these properties, because the only thing that is the same in both instances is the name of the property. The *type* might be different. What should be the result of that?

If you really want to compare the properties, only if T *is* the same for both instances, just use this method:

```
public void DoStuff<T>(MyGeneric<T> objA, MyGeneric<T> objB) 
    where T : struct, IComparable, IConvertible
{
    if (objA.MyProperty.CompareTo(objB.MyProperty) > 0)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

If you don't know `T` at compile time, you can use reflection as Jon suggests or you can use the new `dynamic` keyword if you are using .NET 4:

```
public void DoStuff(MyBaseClass objA, MyBaseClass objB) 
{
    if (objA.GetType().IsGenericType && 
        objA.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MyGeneric<>) &&
        objA.GetType() == objB.GetType()
       )

    {
        dynamic objADyn = objA;
        dynamic objBDyn = objB;
        if (objADyn.MyProperty.CompareTo(objBDyn.MyProperty) > 0)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I meant the type has to be the same but I don't care of what type T is... I guess your method would work but because I don't know the type of T a compile time I can't use it... right?

Comment: If you REALLY don't know the type at compile time, you can't use it, that's right.

Comment: @user520094: Please check the update to my answer. This should help you.

Comment: I do know that T is of type uint, int or float... I could use your method after a type-check. However, I would have to extend my code in case T could be of another type... Sorry I didn't see your update! Damn, your solutions seems great! Too bad I'm using .NET 3.5 :-((

Comment: @user520094: My second sample code with the `dynamic` keyword should work just as it is. No further type check should be required, because it is enforced at compile time, that every instance of type MyGeneric<> has a generic parameter that conforms to the contraints, i.e. every type used in the generic class has to implement IComparable. Therefore, the dynamic code will always work.

Comment: @user520094: Ah, that's a pity. You need to use Jons approach then and use normal reflection.

Comment: Just curious.. how does objADyn know about MyProperty?

Comment: This is evaluated at runtime. Check out these links: (1) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx (2) http://www.hanselman.com/blog/C4AndTheDynamicKeywordWhirlwindTourAroundNET4AndVisualStudio2010Beta1.aspx